# How to stop Google mailApp script after receiving a reply email?

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-api

I have written a script that sends 3 consecutive emails with a set interval between each email. I was wondering if there is a way to stop the script once a reply is received? For example, after the first email is sent out and there is a reply, the script stops and doesn't send the remaining 2 emails.

Comment: Well you wrote the script that sends the emails.  Did you consider checking to see if there was a reply before sending additional emails?

Comment: I'm trying to automate the process so I wouldn't have to check to see if there was a response...

Comment: I mean check to see if there is a response in your app.

Comment: Hmm I figured out a way to do it with GmailApp.search